# How to create a pivot table in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a pivot table but I am getting an error with my last line of code.

```
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim WSD2 As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim FinalCol As Long
Set WSD = Worksheets("SKU Sum")
Set WSD2 = Worksheets("Finelines")

' Select the data for pivot table

FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
FinalCol = WSD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = WSD.Cells(1, 1).Resize(FinalRow, FinalCol)
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set PT = WSD.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=WSD2.Range(A1), TableName:="Pivotab")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: What's your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your current `PivtoCache` line:

```
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
```

With:

```
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
```

**Also**, you are getting the error in the last line, because you are setting the location of the Pivot-Table `WSD2.Range(A1)` , the string inside the brackets need to have `"`. So also modify it to `WSD2.Range("A1")`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But this worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last line with

```
Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WSD2.Range("A1"), TableName:="Pivotab")
```